# Drawing .obj with VBO

Tags: c, opengl, vbo, .obj

I have a problem with drawing a cube with VBO from a .obj file.

Here is the .obj :

```
# cube.obj
#

g cube

v  0.0  0.0  0.0
v  0.0  0.0  1.0
v  0.0  1.0  0.0
v  0.0  1.0  1.0
v  1.0  0.0  0.0
v  1.0  0.0  1.0
v  1.0  1.0  0.0
v  1.0  1.0  1.0

vn  0.0  0.0  1.0
vn  0.0  0.0 -1.0
vn  0.0  1.0  0.0
vn  0.0 -1.0  0.0
vn  1.0  0.0  0.0
vn -1.0  0.0  0.0

f  1//2  7//2  5//2
f  1//2  3//2  7//2 
f  1//6  4//6  3//6 
f  1//6  2//6  4//6 
f  3//3  8//3  7//3 
f  3//3  4//3  8//3 
f  5//5  7//5  8//5 
f  5//5  8//5  6//5 
f  1//4  5//4  6//4 
f  1//4  6//4  2//4 
f  2//1  6//1  8//1 
f  2//1  8//1  4//1
```

To draw it, I first read the objet with the glmReadOBJ function. Next, I extract the information contained in the model generated (with the "trianglulate" function) to be able to create the VBO object and then draw it, here is what I do :

```
void triangulate(GLfloat* vertices, GLfloat* normals, GLMmodel *model)
  {
      int i, j;
      int it = 0;
      GLuint *tempN, *tempV;

      for (int i = 0; i < model->numtriangles; i++)
      {
          tempV = model->triangles[i].vindices;
          tempN = model->triangles[i].nindices;

          for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
          {
              vertices[it] = model->vertices[tempV[j] - 1];
              normals[it] = model->normals[tempN[j] - 1];

              it++;
          }

      }  
  }

  void glmInitVBO(GLMmodel* model, int* vboId)
  {
      GLfloat *vertices = (GLfloat*)malloc(model->numtriangles * 3 * sizeof(GLfloat));
      GLfloat *normals = (GLfloat*)malloc(model->numtriangles * 3 * sizeof(GLfloat));
      triangulate(vertices, normals, model);

      glGenBuffersARB(1, vboId);
      glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, vboId);

      glBufferDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, sizeof(vertices) + sizeof(normals), 0, GL_STATIC_DRAW_ARB);
      glBufferSubDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, 0, sizeof(vertices),vertices);                             // copy vertices starting from 0 offest
      glBufferSubDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, sizeof(vertices), sizeof(normals), normals);         // copy normals after vertices

  }

  void glmDrawVBO(GLMmodel* model, int* vboId)
  {
      GLfloat *vertices = (GLfloat*)malloc(model->numtriangles * 3 * sizeof(GLfloat));
      GLfloat *normals = (GLfloat*)malloc(model->numtriangles * 3 * sizeof(GLfloat));
      triangulate(vertices, normals, model);

      glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, *vboId);


      glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
      glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

      glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, (void*)sizeof(vertices));
      glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

      glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);

      glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);  // disable vertex arrays
      glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);

      glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, 0);
  }
```

In my main, I call glmReadOBJ, then glmInitVBO and finally glmDrawVBO but nothing happens : the window remains black, nothing is drawn. 
I don't know what I did wrong and tried many things for hours, but the only thing I obtain in the end is a black window ...

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 2):

The main issue I see is unrelated to your OpenGL usage, but just a misunderstanding of how the `sizeof` operator works. For example in this code segment (there are more similar cases in the rest of the code):

```
GLfloat *vertices = (GLfloat*)malloc(model->numtriangles * 3 * sizeof(GLfloat));
GLfloat *normals = (GLfloat*)malloc(model->numtriangles * 3 * sizeof(GLfloat));
...
glBufferDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, sizeof(vertices) + sizeof(normals), 0, GL_STATIC_DRAW_ARB);
glBufferSubDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, 0, sizeof(vertices),vertices);                             // copy vertices starting from 0 offest
glBufferSubDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, sizeof(vertices), sizeof(normals), normals);         // copy normals after vertices
```

`vertices` and `normal` are declared as pointer variables. Their sizes are therefore 32 bits (4 bytes) when building in 32-bit mode, and 64 bits (8 bytes) when building in 64-bit mode. So 4/8 are the values you get when using the `sizeof` operator on the variables.

What you need to pass to the `glBufferData()` and `glBufferSubData()` functions is the actual size of the data you allocated, not the size of the pointer. For example:

```
glBufferSubDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, 0, model->numtriangles * 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), vertices);
```

Another problem is with this call in `glmInitVBO()`:

```
glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, vboId);
```

where `vboId` is declared as a pointer to the `int` value that contains the VBO id. However, `glBindBuffer()` takes the id as an argument, not a pointer to the id. So the call should be:

```
glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, *vboId);
```

BTW, these functions have been part of standard OpenGL since about version 1.1. There really shouldn't be a need to use the extension version.

Comment: Well, I changed all the sizeof(vertices) and sizeof(normals) by sizeof(GLfloat) * model->numtriangles * 3 but still, everything remains black ...
I understand that my code was wrong but still nothing is displayed ...

Comment: @Raphallal Spotted another problem, see the added part in the answer.

Comment: Yeah, I spotted that too, however I still have nothing.